# Using Markov Property in solving PDE/SDE

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am solving the (boundary?) value problem (from Bjork I think, see below)

---

[image]

---

By [Feynman-Kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula), any solution has the form of a conditional expectation

$$F(t,x) = E[\psi(X_T)|X_t = x]$$

where

1. $$\psi(x) = x^2$$
2. $\{W_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ is standard Brownian motion in the filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak F, \{\mathfrak F_t\}_{t \in [0,t]}, \mathbb P)$ where $\mathfrak F_t = \mathfrak F_t^W$, the natural filtration of standard Brownian motion.
3. $\{X_t\}_{t \in [0,T]}$ is any (I guess the only different thing is $X_0$, and that doesn't matter?) stochastic process in the same probability space satisfying either of the two SDEs

$$dX_t = \pm \sigma dW_t$$

and thus

$$X_T = X_t \pm \sigma (W_T -W_t)$$

---

So, I try to evaluate $$E[\psi(X_T)|X_t] \tag{*}$$ and then replace $X_t$ with $x$ as follows:

$$(*) = [(X_t \pm \sigma (W_T -W_t))^2|X_t]$$
$$ = E[X_t^2 \pm 2\sigma (W_T -W_t)X_t + (\sigma (W_T -W_t))^2|X_t]$$
$$ = E[X_t^2|X_t] \pm 2\sigma E[(W_T -W_t)X_t|X_t] + E[(\sigma (W_T -W_t))^2|X_t]$$
$$ = X_t^2 \pm 2\sigma X_t E[(W_T -W_t)|X_t] + E[(\sigma (W_T -W_t))^2|X_t]$$
$$ = X_t^2 \pm 2\sigma X_t E[W_T -W_t|X_t] + (\sigma^2)E[(W_T -W_t)^2|X_t]$$

$$ = X_t^2 \pm 2\sigma X_t E[W_T -W_t|\mathscr F_t] + (\sigma^2)E[(W_T -W_t)^2|\mathscr F_t] \tag{**}$$

$$ = X_t^2 \pm 2\sigma X_t E[W_T -W_t] + (\sigma^2)E[(W_T -W_t)^2]$$

$$ = X_t^2 \pm 2\sigma X_t (0) + \sigma^2(T-t)$$

$$ = X_t^2 + (\sigma^2)(T-t)$$

$$\to E[\psi(X_T)|X_t] = X_t^2 + \sigma^2(T-t)$$

$$\to E[\psi(X_T)|X_t=x] = x^2 + \sigma^2(T-t)$$

$$\to F(t,x) = x^2 + \sigma^2(T-t)$$

---

About the use of the Markov property in $(**)$,

I know that $W_T - W_t$ is independent of $\mathfrak{F_t}$, but I think that

$$X_t \ \in \ m \mathfrak F_t \ \to \ W_T - W_t \ \text{is independent of} \ X_t \tag{3}$$

If $(3)$ is wrong, why?

If $(3)$ is right, does this mean we don't need to use the Markov property? Everything after $(2)$ holds if we replace $\mathscr F_t$ with $X_t$? Why/Why not?

---

The problem seems to be taken from Bjork's Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time. I got the problem from my class notes. Neither Bjork nor Wikipedia seems to use the Markov property

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by $dX_t = \pm \sigma dW_t$?

Comment: @saz There are 2 possible SDEs. Same solution in either case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- In *applying* the Feynman-Kac formula, there is no need to use the Markov property.
- In *proving* the Feynman-Kac formula, the Markov property is needed.

Showing that $G(t,x)$ indeed satisfies the PDE requires showing that $G(t,X_t)$ is a martingale which relies on $X_t$ having the Markov property, which it has because it is a solution of an SDE.

Or something like that.

---

From Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think the expression implies such a lack of independence? Intuitively, the Markov property allows expectations conditional on randomness at a single point in time, $t$, to be replaced by expectations conditional on all of the randomness at points in time up to and including time $t$. Thats why $\mathfrak{F}_t$, which includes all the sigma-algebras up to index $t$, becomes relevant.

In fact, by proceeding with the computation and using the independence of $W_T-W_t$ and $\mathfrak{F}_t$ so that,

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(W_T-W_t\right)\,\bigg\vert\,\mathfrak{F}_t\right]{}={}\mathbb{E}\bigg[\left(W_T-W_t\right)\bigg]{}={}0\,,
$$
we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(X_t{}\pm{}\sigma\left(W_T-W_t\right)\right)^2\,\vert\,\mathfrak{F}_t\right]&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[X^2_t{}+{}\sigma^2\left(W_T-W_t\right)^2\pm2X_t\left(W_T-W_t\right)\,\vert\,\mathfrak{F}_t\right]\newline
&{}={}&\mathbb{E}\left[X^2_t\,\vert\,\mathfrak{F}_t\right]{}+{}\sigma^2\mathbb{E}\left[\left(W_T-W_t\right)^2\,\vert\,\mathfrak{F}_t\right]\newline
&&{}\pm2{}\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\left(W_T-W_t\right)\,\bigg\vert\,\mathfrak{F}_t\right]\newline
&{}={}&X_t^2{}+{}\sigma^2\left(T-t\right){}{}\pm2X_t{}\mathbb{E}\left[\left(W_T-W_t\right)\,\bigg\vert\,\mathfrak{F}_t\right]\newline
&{}={}&X_t^2{}+{}\sigma^2\left(T-t\right)\,,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

which is required to hold at each point of realisation for the stochastic process up to, and including time $T$. Consequently,
$$
F(t,x){}={}x^2{}+{}\sigma^2\left(T-t\right)
$$

solves the given PDE.

Comment: What? I know how to compute the expectation. I'm just wondering why those equations won't hold if you replace F_t with X_t. My answer to your 1st question is that in this case, I think, Markov property is not needed, but it might be for different PDE (see penultimate paragraph in OP pls)

Comment: @BCLC, I see. You are wondering why $\sigma(X_t)$ isn't sufficient for the computation, instead of the apparent "overkill" of $\mathfrak{F}_t$?

Comment: @BCLC, ...or asked another way, you are wondering why the problem can't be solved using the random variables $\mathbb{E}[ X_T^2\vert X_t]$, each of which are $\sigma(X_t)$-measurable respectively, instead of the martingale $\mathbb{E}[ X_T^2\vert \mathfrak{F}_t]$, which is adapted to the filtration $\{\mathfrak{F}_t\}_{t\ge 0}$? One reason is the stochastic integrals that justify the solution (e.g. showing rigorously that the solution satisfies the PDE) are defined in terms of martingales. More intuitively, as stated in my answer, the history of the process is required to satisfy the PDE.

Comment: I don't follow at all. :( Again, is the incremement not independent of X_t? To your last statement, why?

Comment: @BCLC, Yes, the increment is independent of $X_t$,...but that is not enough to solve the PDE using a martingale approach since, in general, $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2_T\vert X_t \right]$ is not a martingale adapted to the relevant filtration. It is, however, related to $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2_T\vert \mathfrak{F}_t \right]$ which is a martingale, and the Markov-property allows us to cast our argument in terms of this martingale. And, why is the process history required to satisfy the PDE? Because, we are trying to solve *this* particular PDE with the process; not just any unconstrained process will do.

Comment: Why is it not adapted to relevant filtration? Ah, is it because sto process is supposed to be subscript u for u>t?

Comment: @BCLC, ...not a martingale adapted to the filtration because, for $t>s$, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left[X_T^2\vert X_t\right]  \vert \mathfrak{F}_s\right]\ne\mathbb{E}\left[X_T^2\vert X_s\right]$$, in general.

Comment: Wait. Not rrally following. Your solution is correct. Replace filtration with X_t only => which step is incorrect?

Comment: @BCLC, Replace filtration with $X_t$ only? A filtration is a collection of sigma-algebras, $X_t$ is a random variable? How can you replace one with the other? Please state clearly what you find confusing about my rigorous statement of why $\mathbb{E}\left[X^2_T\vert X_t \right]$ is not a martingale, in general. If you are solving the PDE using a martingale approach, you need to work in terms of martingales.

Comment: X_t represents $\sigma(X_t)$ right? I think I understand your argument, but I don't quite see why mine is wrong

Comment: @BCLC, Okay, if that is what you mean,...replace $\mathfrak{F}_s$ with $\sigma(X_s)$ in what I wrote,...well, you can't in general.  They are not equivalent, though related. $$\sigma(X_s)\subset\mathfrak{F}_s\,.$$ And, even if you were able to do the replacement it would be irrelevant, it seems to me, because you would still need to argue that you have a relevant martingale, so why not simply work with the preferred martingale (explicitly in terms of the filtration $\left\{\mathfrak{F}_t\right\}_{t\ge 0}$) from the start?

Comment: 1 What is the explanation for the strict subset? Wait why not equivalent? The way X_t (dX_t = constant*dW_t) is defined seems to suggest that they are the same. 2 Um, which step exactly does not hold if we don't replace X_t and why?

Comment: @BCLC, :) typos aside (i.e. "$\subseteq$"), I think our discussion might be too long to count as "useful" comments; I suggest we take a break here. If you feel like it, I encourage you to see William's Martingales book (e.g. Section 10.1) or Oksendal's Book (e.g. Chapter 3) for why these sigma-algebras, *by definition*, are not equivalent and, therefore, not interchangeable *in general* ($dX_t=constant*dW_t$ does not imply it). Also, feel free to try and show, rigorously, that $\mathbb{E}\left[X_T^2\vert X_t\right]$ is a martingale and see that you can't. Thanks for the chat and take care!

Comment: ki3i, sorry of the confusion, and thanks for the replies. I now understand why they are not equivalent. I just don't see what is the problem with $E[X_T^2|X_t]$ not being a martingale. So what? How is the solution any different?

Comment: Is my answer wrong?