# How would you find $Y_1$ for the stochastic integral $dY_t = -Y_t \hspace{1mm} dW_t + Y_t \hspace{1mm} dt$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the following stochastic integral 
$$
dY_t = -Y_t \hspace{1mm} dW_t + Y_t \hspace{1mm} dt
$$
with $Y_0 = 1$.

I have managed to evaluate this to deduce that
$$
Y_t = \exp \left( t - \int_0^t dW_t \right)
$$
Thus, assuming that this is correct, I have attempted to find $Y_1$ as follows:
$$
Y_1 = \exp \left( 1 - \int_0^1 dW_t \right) = \exp \left( 1 - [W_1 - W_0] \right) = \exp \left( 1 - W_1 \right)
$$

However, I have written an R script which evaluates $Y_1$ 1000 times using 1000 independently simulated brownian motions. The values returned by this function have mean $e$ and variance $e^3 - e$, which would suggest that the correct solution would be
$$
Y_1 = \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} - W_1 \right)
$$

Which solution is correct?

Comment: Your mistake is to believe that $$\frac{dY_t}{Y_t}=d(\ln Y_t)$$ In fact, for every positive diffusion $(Y_t)$, $$\frac{dY_t}{Y_t}=d(\ln Y_t)+\frac{d\langle Y\rangle_t}{2Y_t^2}$$ which, in the present case, reads $$\frac{dY_t}{Y_t}=d(\ln Y_t)+\frac12dt$$ that is, $$dt-dW_t=d(\ln Y_t)+\frac12dt$$ or, more simply, $$d(\ln Y_t)=\frac12dt-dW_t$$ thus, $$\ln Y_t-\ln Y_0=\frac12t-W_t$$ and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a special case of the [**Geometric Brownian motion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) with $\mu=1$ and $\sigma=-1$.

The derivation, that has your missing factor $\frac{1}{2}$ from [Itô's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma), is concisely stated on the Wikipedia page:

[image]

Comment: Dumb question $\sigma$ can be negative?

Comment: @BCLC As far as I can see, given that samples from $dW_t$ have equal probability for positive and negative counterparts, this would still give the same model.

Comment: Oh thanks! Is that like how [$X_T = X_t \pm \sigma (W_T -W_t)$ and not just $X_T = x + \sigma (W_T -W_t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124771) ?

Comment: @BCLC I wouldn't use the words "that's like how" but I think the answer you want to her is "yes" :)