# SDE of conditional expectation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation

Assume I have an SDE of the form
$$
dX_t = a(X_t, t) dt + b(X_t, t) dW_t, X_0 = x_0.
$$

Let now with $T>t$ denote $f(X_t)$ the conditional expectation of $X_T$,
$$
f(X_t) = E[X_T|X_t]
$$
My questions:

1. Is $f(\cdot )$ an Ito-diffusion? If no, why? If yes, always?
2. What form does $df(X_t)$ have? I know this seems to be just some application of Itos lemma but I got a bit confused with the derivative of the conditional expectation.

My steps so far: with the martingale representation theorem I get a representation of $f$ as the sum of an expectation and an Ito integral. I know have an Ito diffusion constant which I can’t fully link to $X_t$. I’ve seen that I can represent that diffusion term with the Clark-Ocone-theorem but before I went down that rabbit hole I wanted to check whether I am really on the right path here. I also know that I can represent the conditional expectation as an integral over the conditional density, here however I was afraid that it will be a lot more difficult to reconstruct a more explicit link to $a$ and $b$.

In the optimal case I want to represent $df(X_t)$ as functions of $a$ and $b$. I have the feeling it’s simpler if those are differentiable for the beginning, maybe if I get the basic mechanics going I can continue by myself. My main issue right now is that I don’t know what to do about $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$ and how to write down a representation for it.

Possible that this is a simple question - I’d appreciate it if you’d help me a bit with a formal derivation there.

Answer (score 1):

For details see [Using Markov Property in solving PDE/SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124771/using-markov-property-in-solving-pde-sde).

To be clear the deterministic quantity

$$f(x,t):=E[F(X_T)|X_t=x]$$

is different from the random quantity

$$Y_{t}:=E[F(X_T)|\sigma(X_t)]$$

which is equal to

$$f(X_{t},t):=E[F(X_T)|\mathcal{F}_t]$$
by the Markov property of SDEs (see Schilling 21.24 Corollary).

The $f(x,t)$ is a deterministic solution to the backward equation eg. as explained [Lesson 5, SDE and PDE](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Egoodman/teaching/StochCalc2018/notes/Lesson5.pdf) and the random $f(X_{t},t)$ is a martingale (as shown in [Using Markov Property in solving PDE/SDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124771/using-markov-property-in-solving-pde-sde.))

The random quantity $Z_{t}=f(X_{t},t)$ does **not** necessarily satisfy a diffusion, it simply satisfies the follow *stochastic pde*

$$f(X_{t},t)=\int^{t} f_{x}(X_{s},s) b((X_{s},s)) dW_{s},$$

so it is not an [Itô diffusion](https://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_diffusion) where the only independent variable is time $t$.

For this to return to being an Ito diffusion you would need a relation

$$f_{x}(X_{s},s)=g(f(X_{s},s))$$

for some function $g$, which is generally not true. For example it fails even for Brownian motion where $f(x,t)$ is in terms of Gaussian since the backward-equation is $f_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\Delta f=0$ as done [here](https://math.nyu.edu/%7Egoodman/teaching/StochCalc2020/week3/Week3.pdf)

$$f(x,t)=E[X_{T}|X_{t}=x]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (T-t)}}e^{-\frac{(y-x)^{2}}{2(T-t)}}dy.$$

Comment: Might just be a typo but: the backward equation is $f_t+\frac12 \Delta f=0$ (with terminal condition). The *forward equation*, or Fokker Planck equation is $f_t = \frac12 \Delta f$ (with initial condition) has solution $f=$ a Gaussian (PDF).

Comment: I agree and I upvote. Thanks.

Comment: That goes into a better direction! I’m curious about three things: 1) where does that SPDE come from?  Would that even be well-defined? 2) I agree with it not being an Ito diffusion but can it still be a general Ito process?

Comment: 3) if I compare your statement with Clark-Ocone, I don’t see immediately why they should be equivalent. Could you shed some light on that? It goes into a similar direction but I’m not so sure why you’d have an additional $b$ in there.

Comment: @freistil90 in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124771/using-markov-property-in-solving-pde-sde, they go in detail or you can go directly to the Shreve-Karatzas chapter they mention.

Comment: @freistil90 if by "general Ito process", you mean coefficients the depend on t too $b(t,X)$, then no as the above example shows. Clark-Ocone, says there is some representative $u(s)$, so here we concretely have $u(s)=f_{x}(X_{s},s) b((X_{s},s)) $.

Answer (score -2):

Let $f(t,x) = \mathbb{E}(X_T|X_t=x)$ for any $(t,x) \in [0, T]\times \mathbb{R}$. By [Feynman-Kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) it follows that the Kolmogorov-Backward PDE is satisfied: $\partial_t f+a(t, x) \partial_x f+ 0.5 b(t,x)^2 \partial_{xx}^2 f = 0$ for $(t,x)\in[0,T)\times \mathbb{R}$ and $f(T,x)=x$ for all $x$. If you apply Ito's formula to $Y_t = f(t, X_t)$ then you get $dY_t = \partial_x u(t, X_t) b(t, X_t) dW_t$ using the PDE. Thus $Y_t = f(t, X_t)$ is an Ito process, driftless and a martingale provided $a$ and $b$ are nice enough. If the solution of the Backward-PDE has a closed form, you can compute $\partial_x u(t,x)$ exactly.

By the way, many authors use the term *diffusion* to refer to coefficients that are time-independent $a(t,x)=a(x)$ and $b(t,x)=b(x)$ and say Ito processes for the more general case.

Comment: If anyone has corrections or suggestions, I'll gladly address them.